# param show zero in model summary, when custom layer is used in making model

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to build an InceptionNet. I built a custom inception unit. Somehow when I use it in my model, the total parameters in model summary are displayed zero. Can anyone kindly guide me on where I am making a mistake.

**Code for inception unit layer**

```
class InceptionUnit(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, filters, activation='relu', **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.filters = filters
    self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)

  def call(self, inputs):
    out1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[0], kernel_size=1, 
                               padding='SAME')(inputs)
    out1 = self.activation(out1)
    out2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[1], kernel_size=1,
                               padding='SAME')(inputs)
    out2 = self.activation(out2)
    out2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[2], kernel_size=3,
                               padding='SAME')(out2)
    out2 = self.activation(out2)
    out3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[3], kernel_size=1,
                               padding='SAME')(inputs)
    out3 = self.activation(out3)
    out3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[4], kernel_size=5,
                               padding='SAME')(out3)
    out3 = self.activation(out3)
    out4 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=1,
                                     padding='SAME')(inputs)
    out4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters[5], kernel_size=1,
                               padding='SAME')(out4)
    out4 = self.activation(out4)
    out = keras.layers.concatenate([out1, out2, out3, out4])
    return out
```

**Code for model:**

```
filters = [[64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32],
           [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64],
           [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64],
           [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64],
           [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64],
           [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64],
           [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128],
           [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128],
           [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128]]

model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, strides=2, 
                              padding='SAME', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='SAME'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME', 
                              activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='SAME', ))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[0]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='SAME'))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[2]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[3]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[4]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[5]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[6]))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='SAME'))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[7]))
model.add(InceptionUnit(filters[8]))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1000, activation='softmax'))
```

This is the output of model.summary()
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
I was creating layers in call method. Instead I should be making them inside **init** method and then use them in call method.